# add an additional secondary image to be associated with the category

Tags: image, wordpress, categories, wordpress-featured-image

I have seen the plugin to add a secondary featured image to a post or a page in wordpress. I  need to have secondary featured images for ‘categories’. I can associate a picture with a category by using ‘Taxonomy Images’ plugin. (http://wordpress.mfields.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/), however, I want to  add  an additional secondary image to be associated with the category.
Please tell me how I can solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-images/

It appears to let you have multiple images....

Rick